# Handle two checkbox components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have `checkboxgroup` component (parent component), and `checkbox` (child component). I want to handle these 2 checkboxgroup components `Fruits` and `Vegetables`in the same page with `changeHandler` and get the checked options for each of them. But i got this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: prev[name] is not iterable

```
interface SelectedOptions {
  [name: string]: string[];
}

const Fruits = [
  {
    label: "Banana",
    value: "Banana",
  },
  {
    label: "Orange",
    value: "Orange",
  },
];

const Vegetable = [
  {
    label: "Carrot",
    value: "Carrot",
  },
  {
    label: "Potatoes",
    value: "Potatoes",
  },
];

export function HomePage() {
  const [checkBoxOptions, setCheckBoxOptions] = useState<SelectedOptions>({});

  const changeHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { value, checked, name } = e.target;

    if (checked) {
      setCheckBoxOptions((prev: SelectedOptions) => ({
        ...prev,
        [name]: [...prev[name], value],   /////error is here
      }));
    } else {
      setCheckBoxOptions((prev: SelectedOptions) => ({
        ...prev,
        [name]: [...prev[name].filter((option: string) => option !== value)],
      }));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
          <CheckBoxGroup
            checkBoxOptions={Fruits}
            name={"Fruits"}
            changeHandler={changeHandler}
          />
          <CheckBoxGroup
            checkBoxOptions={Vegetable}
            name={"Vegetables"}
            changeHandler={changeHandler}
          />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue should because your initial state, as an object, is defined, but does not have the initial properties that will later be accessed by `name` variable.

So you can either initialize state like

```
 const [checkBoxOptions, setCheckBoxOptions] = useState<SelectedOptions>({
    Fruits: [],
    Vegetables: [] });
```

or access them like  `[name]: [...(prev[name] || []), value]` with empty array fallback so you can still spread the values.